Howto derive label from a list of alternatives
I want to migrate from one label convention to another. Therefore, I'd like promtail to derive its labels from a list of source labels taking the first that is available.
The solution should also work if both labels are present.
I tried some variations of:
- action: replace
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_my_old_label
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_my_new_label
        target_label: exposed_label

